# Spring MVC - Getting page not found while using jquery load function

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

Web.xml

```
    ...
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.spring.springMVC</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
 ...
```

Mvc Configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.spring.springMVC")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }


}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public ModelAndView test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        return new ModelAndView("form");
    }
}
```

form.jsp

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Twitter Bootstrap 3 Fluid Layout Example</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("header.html"); 
  $("#footer").load("footer.html");
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">

<div id="header"></div>
<!--Remaining section-->
<div id="footer"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

header & footer htmls are on the same location where form.jsp is.
webapp
     resources
            js
            css
     web-inf
           views
              form.jsp
              header.html
              footer.html

I am getting page not found for header & footer.html. If I try same example without spring mvc (only jsp, servlet) then it works fine. Is there any issue with the configuration?

Comment: you servlet-mapping url-pattern is set to `/` - shouldn't it be `/*`? but also keep in mind that jQuery is asking to load `<app_context>/header.html` and you mentioned the `header.html` page is located inside `WEB-INF\views` which is not reachable from an external source (i.e. your client's browser) - you will have to move your html pages out of the `WEB-INF\views` folder and onto the web-app root

Comment: do you have any other configuration to handle `header.html` and `footer.html` - I only see  `@RequestMapping(value="/")` (which returns the view: `form`) but I don't see other methods returning `footer` or `header` as their views

Comment: No. I didn't set any config for header & footer html. What config do I need to set for this?  I will move this htmls to web-app root folder to see if that works. What should be its relative path then? Is   $("#header").load("../header.html"); fine?

Comment: You can leave them where they are and see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to rename your pages from `.html` to `.jsp` (i.e. `header.jsp` and `footer.jsp`) - leave them where they are right now (in `WEB-INF\views`) and also add these in your Controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public ModelAndView getForm(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        return new ModelAndView("form");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/header.html")
    public ModelAndView getHeader(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        return new ModelAndView("header");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/footer.html")
    public ModelAndView getFooter(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        return new ModelAndView("footer");
    }
}
```

The reason for the not found messages is that you are telling your servlet to handle all the requests (`url-pattern:'/'`) so when jQuery requests the `header.html` page, it gets handled by the servlet and sent to the controller.

The controller knows how to handle a request with a URL pattern of `/` (the first method) but it has no way of knowing how to handle `header.html` or `footer.html` which is why we added the other two methods.

Ideally, you would not want to make three requests to the servlet for each page called (too much overhead). Instead, make your original JSP page (i.e. form.jsp) include all the other two pages (via `<@ include ...@>` syntax) to avoid having to write a new method for each new page.

You could also add a pattern (like the view resolver for the JSP pages themselves) but, again you are making multiple calls (in this case 3) per page, which is not ideal.

Comment: Is there any xml/MvcConfiguration (above) class based configuration instead of adding it inside controller?

Comment: Instead of configuring it, I would exclude the `html` pages from the `url-pattern` so that you don't have to deal with them inside the MVC at all.  (Really, there is no need for it, the servlet container can simply output the html page by itself without having to parse it into the MVC framework)